# needed solution for issue either by CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

When i click on the button the last `div.popUp` show be at the place of 3rd div `.delet` and `.delet` container have to be disappear.

As referred to my jsfiddle link when i click  the last element `div.popUp` overlap on the 3rd element `.delet` . so i can't achieve the background color.

Am in a condition to define the background color in rgba value only.

need to achive:
When button is clicked the `.delet` container should move towards left and the `popUp` div also move towards left as in the previous place of `.delet`

needed solution for this issue either by CSS or jQuery

LINK :http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/wxab9Ldn/12/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){***})
```

changes the reference of this.
you should use apply/call to put the reference of this explicitly